# active class assignment in a menu with submenu JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code for creating a menu with submenu using a json via ajax call but I cannot assign the active class to the menu item when I am in a submenu page.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $.getJSON('../../menu2.html', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {

      let menu = $('#side-menu');
      $('#side-menu').metisMenu('dispose'); //For stop and destroy metisMenu

      var current_page = document.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0];

      var class_item = "";
      if (item.nomemenu == current_page) {
             var class_item = "active";
           }


      var arrow = "";
      if (item.submenu == "true") {
        var arrow = '<span class="fa arrow"></span>';
      }


      var html = '<li id="menu-' + item.nomemenu + '" class="' + class_item + '">';

      html += '<a href="#" id="' + item.title + '">' +
        '<i class="' + item.icon + '"></i>' +
        '<span class="nav-label">' + item.title + '</span>' + arrow + '</a>';

            // SubMenu
            if (item.submenu == "true") {

              html += '<ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse" name="subelenco">';

                  //SubMenu Loop
                  $.each(item.subitems, function (i, subitem) {

                       if(subitem.link==current_page){
                         var active_link = 'active';
                       }else{ var active_link = ''; }

                   html += '<li class="'+active_link+'" nomemenu="'+ subitem.nomemenu +'"><a href="#" id="' + subitem.link + '" nomemenu="'+ subitem.nomemenu +'">' + subitem.title + '</a></li>';

                  });



              html += '</ul>';

            }


      html += '</li>';

      menu.append(html);
      $('#side-menu').metisMenu(); //For stop and destroy metisMenu

    });
  });


});
```

I want to assign the active class to the element that has as id "menu-subitem.nomemenu" when subitem.link = current_page .

I tried to insert the code **$('# menu -' + subitem.nomemenu).addClass('active')** inside the submenu loop, but i don't know whyinside that loop the jquery selector doesn't work in any way.

Do you know any alternative ways with which I can succeed in obtaining this result?

Comment: Can someone help me?